# I am facing problem when trying to Log token of my device for FCM on Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here I got this Error while trying to Log Token.

Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException:
> AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.

Here is my code which may cause problem:

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String TAG=MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
     super.onNewToken(token);
     Log.d(TAG, "Token :"+token);
  }
}
```

My manifest file is here:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
             android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>enter code here
```

Please help or suggest me some thread on how to work with FCM.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest like this

```
<service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

somehow it resolved mine